# Unexpected output from Block execution flow

Tags: c#

This is the sample code I wrote, to understand the output and how the finally block executes:

```
public static void finallyBlockExecution(int num)
{
    try
    {
        if (num != 14)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("num is {0}", num);
            exceptionMethod(++num);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Finally executed.. {0}", num);
    }
}
```

When i call the method like this: `ClassA.finallyBlockExecution(10);`
the output is:

```
num is 10
num is 11
num is 12
num is 13
finally executed.. 14
finally executed.. 14
finally executed.. 13
finally executed.. 12
finally executed.. 11
```

I know that `finally` will be executed 5 times, but I am not able to figure out why it is printing 14 twice.

Comment: please show the code that calls this method

Comment: <Class A> { static void Main(string[] args)
        { <ClassName B>.exceptionMethod(10); } } that method is define in class B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When program flow reaches try block and if finally block is defined, finally block will always be executed in any case. Method can not return without executing finally block. That's why 'finally executed.. 14' is printed twice. Imagine we have the following code block.

```
 public int DoSomeCalculation()
 {
   int a=0;
   try
   {
     //perform some calculations
     return a;
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
    return -1;
   }
   finally
   {
   Console.WriteLine("Do some cleanup");
   }
  }
```

Here finally block will be executed whether method returns from try or catch block.